# JavaScript / jQuery: Update HTML on select list change

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, select

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

http://jsfiddle.net/sscovil/Ju6mN/

I'm trying to get this price calculator to automatically update when a change is made in one of the select lists. It's not grabbing the selectedIndex value for some reason...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are declaring `x` and `y` multiple times in the same scope and changing the values. Don't do that.

Comment: When setting up your `.on` handlers, you are calling CalculatePrice() during setup and setting its return value as the callback for the change events

Comment: And `discountMultiplier` is not defined, so that's throwing an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have forked your fiddle, working version is here - http://jsfiddle.net/nBqWE/6/

It had the following problems:

1. `discountMultiplier` variable not defined
2. Incorrect event handler assignment, should be `$('#duration').on('change', CalculatePrice);` instead of `$('#duration').on('change', CalculatePrice());`
3. You were getting select value in a very strange way, if you use jQuery there is a `val()` function available - `project[0] = parseInt($('#hours').val());`

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you are invoking the function directly inside the `on` function, what you want to do is assign the function to the event. So it will be

```
$("#duration").on('change',CalculatePrice)
```

not

```
$("#duration").on('change',CalculatePrice())
```

The latter will call the function immediately.

Comment: Thank you! Also, I forgot that I had renamed the multiplier variable, as Sergey pointed out...